# Using a case when statement with date where a condition is within today

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I have to find out whether an order is placed within 90 minutes of creation, after 90 minutes but same day and then the days after that.

I'm using a case when statement for that:

case when order <= 90 then 'within 90 minutes'
etc

What case when statement can I use for after 90 minutes but within the same day?

Comment: You should show some data sample to find out data types you are using. It can be date or timestamp or sophisticated number or text or whatever human imagination can possibly do.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the column `order` has data type timestamp you can try the following `case ...`: (see [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=41ca73837b10a75e9ba9611d4ead4a42))

```
select id
     , order_tm
     , case when current_timestamp - order_tm < interval '90 minutes' 
            then 'within 90 minutes'

            when current_date = order_tm::date
            then 'same day, but >= 90 minutes ago'

            else (extract ('day' from current_timestamp - order_tm))::text || ' days ago'
       end "When Ordered" 
 from orders;
```

**Note:** Using *order* as a column name is a very poor choice. It is both a Postgres and a SQL Standard [reserved word](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html). While you can currently get away with doing so that could change in the future as it is documented and has been for quite some time. At best using a reserved word as a column name leads to confusion.